# C2146: syntax : missing ')' before identifier 's'

Tags: c++, string

So I this is a sample code. I just started using Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition, and I keep getting this error along with others but this bothers me a lot.

> Program 9.cpp(15): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 's'

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Salesman
{
    char name[26];
    float total_sales;
public:
    Salesman (char *s, float f)
    {
        strcpy(name s);  //Error occurs here. :(
        total_sales=f;
    }
    void prnobject (void)
    {
        cout<<this->name;
        cout<<"\tHas invoked probject: \n";
    }
};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    salesman Raman ("Raman", 21450), Sita ("Sita", 23190), Vedant ("Vedant", 19142);
    Raman.prnobject();
    Sita.prnobject();
    Vedant.prnobject();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Your constructor should also bem Salesman (const char *s, float f) for correctness since you don't want to modify the input string param and you should probably check for copy overflow (name is limited to 25 chars + nul terminator) or use std::string instead and remove all these headaches

Comment: Ehm, @BoltClock♦, did you just edit this question to read "So I this is a sample code."?

Comment: @Mr Lister: It was there all along, but I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a comma:

```
 strcpy(name, s);
```

C++ requires that you separate your arguments with a comma - you can't just list the names with spaces separating the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

```
strcpy(name, s); 
           ^^^
```

You missed the comma.

Answer (score 3):

Change `strcpy(name s);  //Error occurs here. :(`

To

`strcpy(name, s);`

No comment as recommended.

Comment: You forgot to fix the comment: `// No error occurs here :)` Outdated comments are a real pain in the neck.

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler complains about missing or unexpected punctuation, or suggests you put certain characters at certain places, you have a *syntax error*. Don't put too much effort into fitting the precise error message to your code, though. You'll just get frustrated and confused. Instead, pretend the compiler has given a more generic error message merely telling you there is a syntax error *somewhere on that line*. Then use your own knowledge of C++ syntax to find and correct the error yourself. (The error might actually be on an earlier line; if you omit a semicolon or closing brace, for example, the compiler will often highlight a line later in the file.)

I suspect you were focused on figuring out where the missing parenthesis should go. If that suggestion hadn't been planted in your mind, you probably would have figured out on your own that you were actually missing a comma between the two function arguments:

```
strcpy(name, s);
```

The compiler suggests a parenthesis because a closing parenthesis is its *best guess* for what would make the code syntactically valid at that point. The compiler hasn't yet done semantic analysis to determine that `strcpy` is a function that needs two arguments, and it hasn't yet read far enough to recognize the closing parenthesis later on the line, so it doesn't know that a comma would be a better suggestion for fixing the error. The compiler suggests the *minimum* change necessary for fixing the *most basic* error it can detect given the amount of code it's read so far.